# System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary `Add` vs set `Item`

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, dictionary

If i wish to put items into a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`, I can either `Add` or set the `Item`.

I know if we do `Add` it checks if the key already exists and if not it throws an exception.

So when adding a ton of items, should I prefer setting `Item` instead of `Add`, since `Add` does unnecessary checks that may actually slow things down?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is what happens when you set Item:

```
public void set_Item(TKey key, TValue value)
{
    this.Insert(key, value, false);
}
```

Here is what happens when you add item:

```
public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
{
    this.Insert(key, value, true);
}
```

The last parameter last bool `add` parameter just affects this line:

```
if (add)
{
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Argument_AddingDuplicate);
}
```

So if you want exception when you add a duplicate item, you need to use Add. If you want to overwrite exiting item you need to set Item.

Comment: is that `set_Item` public really? I can't find it in intellisense. Any idea?

Comment: nawfal - `set_Item` is the method that is called by CLR when you do assignments like `myArray[1] = x`.
In other words when you add index property `public string this[int index]` to your class, compiler adds behind the scene one method `get_Item` for indexed property getter and one method `set_Item` method indexed property setter. Whether they are public or not depends on how exactly you defined your indexed property. Every regular property has one or two methods underneath as well (getter and setter).

Answer (score 3):

That all depends on whether you want to handle duplicate keys or overwrite any potentially existing item. To check for duplicates you can use:

- [ContainsKey method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) to check if a key exists.
- [TryGetValue method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) to check if the key exists and get the value if available.

For example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

Console.WriteLine(dict.ContainsKey(1)); // false
dict[1] = "hi";
dict[1] = "hello"; // "hi" is overwritten

// true: hello
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", dict.ContainsKey(1), dict[1]);

// TryGetValue if checking by key and interested in the value
string result;
if (dict.TryGetValue(1, out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key 1 exists: " + result);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key 1 not found");
}
```

Comment: Would `Contains` be better for the checking duplicates?

Comment: @Alex the `ContainsKey` or `ContainsValue` methods provided by the `Dictionary` class would be a good choice. Did you mean those or `Enumerable.Contains`? If the latter, it would require casting the `Keys` collection first such as `dict.Keys.Cast<int>().Contains(1)` which isn't worthwhile given the available methods provided.

Comment: @Alex no prob. Yeah, `ContainsKey` would be better than `TryGetValue` if we're only concerned with checking for an existing key. `TryGetValue` just came to mind first in my initial sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Throwing exceptions are cheap, its handling them that is expensive. The try portion of the try/catch block runs like normal. When a catch block is executed, it has to unwind the stack to populate the stack trace (among other things). This is what makes exceptions expensive. This is the reason to avoid catching exceptions if you you have the means to do so by using methods such as `Dictionary<T>.ContainsKey`

It is highly unlikely that you will ever notice the performance difference between calling Add and setting Item. So use the one that is most appropriate for the situation.

Update:
Don't optimize your code unless it is slow.